# match strings in list and DF column and put into new DF column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

using python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns and about a million rows. The third column contains strings. I want to select a subset of these strings that match the strings in a list and put them in a fourth column.

Here is an example of a string from the dataframe:

```
"BW - Jl 8 '79 - pE2 CCB-B -vl9-Ja '66-p83 LJ - v91 - Ja 15 -66 - p426 
NYRB - v5 - D 9 '65 - p39 NYTBR - v70 - N 21 '65 - p60 Nat R - vl7 - 
D14 '65-pll65 y"
```

Here is a sample of my list:

```
['AAA', 'A Anth', 'AAPSS-A', 'A Anth', 'A Arch', 'A Art', 'AB', 'ABA 
Jour', 'ABC', 'ABR', 'AC', 'ACSB', 'Adult L', 'Advocate', 'AE', 'AER', 
'AF', 'Africa T', 'Afterimage', 'Aging', 'AH', 'AHR', 'A Hy R', 'AIQ', 
'AJA', 'AJES', 'AJMD', 'AJMR', 'AJP', 'A J Psy', 'AJS', 'AL', 'A Lead', 
'A Lib', 'Am', 'Am Ant', 'Am Arts', 'Am Craft', 'Amer R', 'Am Ethol', 
'Am Film', 'Am Mus Teach', 'Am Q', 'Ams', 'Am Sci', 'Am Spect', 'Am 
Threat', 'Analog', 'ANQ', 'ANQ:QJ', 'Ant & Col Hob', 'Antiq', 'Antiq 
J', 'Ant R', 'Apo', 'APR', 'APSR', 'AR', 'ARBA', 'Arch', 'Archt R', 
'ARG', 'Armchair Det', 'Art Am', 'Art Bull', 'Art Dir', 'Art J', 'Art 
N', 'AS', 'ASBYP', 'Aspen A', 'Aspen J', 'ASR', 'Astron', 'Ath J', 
'Atl', 'Atl Pro Bk R', 'Atl PBR', 'Aud', 'AW', 'BALF', 'Ballet N', 
"Barron's", 'BAS', 'BB', 'B&B', 'BC', 'BCM', 'B Ent', 'Belles Let', 
'BF', 'BFYC', 'B Hor', 'BHR', 'BIC', 'Biography', 'BksW', 'Bks for 
Keeps', 'Bks for YP', 'BL', 'Bloom Rev']
```

From the string in the dataframe, I want to select 'BW', 'CCB-B', 'LJ', 'NYRB', 'NYTRB', and 'Nat R', (all of which are in the list) and put them in a new column in the same row.

My code looks like this:

```
s = df65['Review'].str.extractall(reviews_list).squeeze()
s = s.unstack(level=-1)
df65['Reviews'] = s
```

But extractall doesn't take lists as arguments in this way.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.extractall` expects a regex pattern as a parameter. You can make this regex with

```
'|'.join(reviews_list)
```

But some characters need to be escaped to be used with regex, so import `re` and use `re.escape` like this:

```
[re.escape(item) for item in reviews_list]
```

So your new call will be

```
 s = df65['Review'].str.extractall('|'.join([re.escape(item) for item in reviews_list])).squeeze()
```

Comment: with this code, i get the error: ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups —— how would i change the code in the extractall parens to make that a regex capture group?

Comment: Surround it with parens :) I think I actually deleted them from my post by accident so check and old edit, I'll fix it when I'm at a computer

Comment: for some reason, it gives me the same error if I put the whole thing in parens

Comment: '(' + '|'.join([re.escape(item) for item in reviews_list]) + ')'

Comment: great, works, thanks! :) . One slip up. The regex grabs indiscriminately: ie. 'NYRB' is a common abbrev, but the regex just pulls 'NY' b/c that is also an abbrev. Is there an easy way too get the regex to grab the longest match rather than the shortest?

Comment: If you know that it's going to be surrounded by whitespace that's probably your best bet